# How to blur a textarea in IE9 using ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a read only textarea and what I am trying to do is simple: remove the caret whenever user select / click on the textarea.

The easiest way I can think of is use JQuery to register a callback event on the textarea, and I know IE has its own problems that we must use a setTimeout() for safety.

```js
 setTimeout(function () {
   $('textarea[readonly]').focus(function () {
     this.blur();
   });
}, 100);
```

However, it works in Chrome but totally not work in IE9!!
I have replace `this.blur()` to other codes like `this.innerHTML = "test"`, it works as expected, so that means the problem is the `blur()` function...

So how can I achieve what I am trying to in IE9

**EDITED**

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8rvp9203/1/

As I was using ASP.NET, the html here is the rendered html instead of raw .aspx markup

**EDITED 2**

To all who is interested, please see my comment in the answer of @Phill

Comment: make the jsfiddle of your html and javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let jQuery handle the Blur for you by changing `this.blur()` to `$(this).blur()`

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('textarea[readonly]').focus(function () {
        $(this).blur();
   });
}, 100);
```

Works fine in IE 9.

Also, not entirely sure why you have the setTimeout? It's not needed... It only doesn't work because you're running your jQuery code before the page is ready. It would be more correct to do something like:

```
$(function () {
   $('textarea[readonly]').focus(function () {
        $(this).blur();
   });
});
```

---

Edit: v1.10.1

I don't know if that's a problem with jsfiddle, but all CDN provided urls I give to V 1.10.1, or the included jsfiddle version, all get `Access is denied` in the Dev Tools for that 1 version. So jQuery isn't loaded which is why it's not working.

Edit 2:

https://blog.jquery.com/2013/07/03/jquery-1-10-2-and-2-0-3-released/

There was a bug fix in 1.10.2 which states:

#13980: JQuery library does not load in Opera 12.15 and IE 10 in IFrame which content is loaded from external domain

This could be what was causing the problem on jsfiddle.

Comment: just about the same time I found out how to solve the problem, but I do not know why: In JSFiddle, if I use JQuery1.10.1, then my code does not work IE9 (works in Chrome), but for any other version of JQuery, it works normally in IE9 as well ! Upvoted but it needs not use $(this)... Still do not know why only version 1.10.1 not working though...

Comment: @shole - added an edit. Seems to be just that version is not being loaded.

Comment: then i wonder why only IE9 not working but Chrome works...? also in my development project it still not work no matter using this or $(this)…

Comment: @shole I can't get it to work in IE 8/9/10 with V1.10.1 at all, but works fine with 1.10.2. But v1.10.1 works fine in Chrome/FF/Safari

Comment: Yea I think it is the problem...turns out it is a fixed bug catching me..answer accepted :)